# using bash to loop a script with multiple conditions

Tags: bash, loops

I am attempting to add a parameter based on an additional list 'list2.txt' that I have created and I am not quite sure how to implement it.

My running code

```
while read i
do
sed "s/Pie/$i/g" old_script.sh > new_script.$i.sh
sbatch new_script.$i.sh
done<list.txt
```

But I want to add the following condition with based on a new list... and I am not quite sure how to implement it into my working script

```
sed "s/Apple/__/g"
```

Comment: so add my new sed command before the original sed command with a temp output. but where we would i indicate the list2.txt

Comment: `sed -e "s/Pie/$i/g" -e "s/Apple/__/g" old_script.sh > new_script.$i.sh` (**note:** each *expression* is preceded by `-e`)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` allows several ways to supply multiple commands. You can give them individually with `-e` or just write them into a single script string.

GNU `sed` allows commands on the same line to be separated with semicolons, and is genrally what you will find, but if you don't have that version you can use embedded newlines. As long as it's quoted it will work fine.

```
sed "s/Pie/$i/g; s/Apple/__/g;" old_script.sh # GNU specific but common
```

or

```
sed "
  s/Pie/$i/g
  s/Apple/__/g
" old_script.sh # general, should always work.
```

These are both valid.